# Segue and delegates in UIKit

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, segue

I have 2 Controllers: MainVC and SideMenuVC.

I wanted to modify *MainVC using SideMenuVC*, so created delegate of SideMenuVC ( as well, there's *Emdebed segue "name..." to "Side Menu View Controller"* on storyboard because MainViewController has subView, which contains *ContainerView* - this container is our SideMenuVC. And this delegate works as he should.

However, due to logic in the app, I also need to send data from **MAINVC** to **SIDEMENUVC**.

So i did the same - created another delegate of second VC... But I turned out, MainViewControllerDelegate is not responding in SideMenuViewController. And i'm absolutely clueless...

Yes, i do implement necessary protocols in both classes, in extension!

### Code of both VCs below, screens of storyboard in the attachment

**MainViewController + MainViewControllerDelegate**

```swift
protocol MainViewControllerDelegate{
    func isImageLoaded(_ isLoaded:Bool)
}

class MainViewController: UIViewController {
    /* ... */
    
    var delegate: MainViewControllerDelegate?
    var sideMenuViewController: SideMenuViewController?
    
    private var isSideMenuPresented:Bool = false
    private var isImageLoaded:Bool = false
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.isImageLoaded = false
        self.setupUI()
        self.delegate?.isImageLoaded(false)
    }
    
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if (segue.identifier == "MainVC_SideMenuVC_Segue")
        {
            if let controller = segue.destination as? SideMenuViewController
            {
                self.sideMenuViewController = controller
                self.sideMenuViewController?.delegate = self
            }
        }
    }
/* ... */
//I'm using PHPicker, and when new image is selected, i want to send "true" via delegate
  func picker(_ picker: PHPickerViewController, didFinishPicking results: [PHPickerResult]) {
        dismiss(animated: true)
        if let itemProvider = results.first?.itemProvider, itemProvider.canLoadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self){
            let previousImage = self.presentedImage.image
            itemProvider.loadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self){ [weak self] image, error in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    guard let self = self, let image = image as? UIImage, self.presentedImage.image == previousImage else {
                        return
                    }
                    self.presentedImage.image = image
                    self.isImageLoaded = true;
                    self.delegate?.isImageLoaded(true)
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
```

**SideMenuViewController + SideMenuViewControllerDelegate**

```swift
protocol SideMenuViewControllerDelegate{
    func hideSideMenu() 
    func performAction(_ type:OperationType)
}

class SideMenuViewController: UIViewController {
/*...*/
    
    var delegate: SideMenuViewControllerDelegate?
    var mainViewController: MainViewController?
    
    private var menuData: [ExpandingCellModel] = []
    private var isImageLoaded: Bool = false
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
      //  self.mainViewController?.delegate = self
        menuData = setupData()
        setupUI()
    }
    
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let controller = segue.destination as? MainViewController {
            controller.delegate = self
        }
    }
}
```

/* ... [image: View of storyboard]*/

Comment: The instance of `SideMenuViewController` is created while the segue is being performed. If you need a permanent reference it might be a better choice to `instantiate` the second controller and `present` it.

Comment: @vadian I tried something like this :
In MainViewControll changed override of prepere

           `if let _ = segue.destination as? SideMenuViewController
            {
                self.sideMenuViewController = SideMenuViewController(mainViewController: self)
                self.sideMenuViewController?.delegate = self`

Did  init(with: MainViewController) in SideMenu, but i get error from 
`required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("This class does not support NSCoder")
}`

Comment: This is still worse. In any case you have to ask the storyboard for the instance, you get it for free in the segue or as I said you have to instantiate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I **think** is happening.

There is segue **happening** from MainVC to SideMenuVC but there is no segue **actually happening** between SideMenuVC to MainVC in my opinion.

**Happening** is keyword because there is an EmbedSegue from MainVC to SideMenuVC but where is the segue from SideMenuVC to MainVC ? You did some connection in storyboard but nothing is **happening** in my opinion.

That is why in `override func prepare` is being called as planned in `MainViewControllerDelegate` and the delegate is getting set but it is not getting set in `SideMenuViewController` since `override func prepare` doesn't get called as no segue **happens**.

What you can do instead which might work is set both the delegates inside `prepare` in `MainViewControllerDelegate`

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if (segue.identifier == "MainVC_SideMenuVC_Segue")
        {
            if let sideMenuVC = segue.destination as? SideMenuViewController
            {
                sideMenuVC.delegate = self
                
                // assign MainViewControllerDelegate here
                self.delegate = sideMenuVC
            }
        }
    }
```

Check now if data is sent back to main view controller also.

If your issue is still not yet solved, please have a look and try [this small example I set for you in github](https://github.com/shawn-frank/Passing-Data-In-Embed-Segues-iOS) to show passing data between mainVC and embeddedVC and it might give you some hints.

You can see the result of this in action here: https://youtu.be/J7C7SEC04_E